# Find out which instance threw an exception in a try-catch block

Tags: java, exception

Is there any way in Java to find out "who"/"what" threw the excpetion?

consider the following code which validates a couple of Textfields (which have certain constraint on what input is valid or not). I want to mark the corresponding textfield red.

```
public void validateInput() {
    try {
        textfieldName.validate();
        textfieldAge.validate();
    } catch (InvalidInputExcpetion e) {
        // Pseudocode
        // e.getThrower() would get me the reference to the Object which threw the exception
        (TextField e.getThrower()).markRed();
    }
}
```

The only solution I found is to extend my custom excpetion to hold a reference to the throwing textfield, isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Using a custom exception is the way to go here, since handling the exception is the same for all instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your code in two `try catch`

```
public void validateInput() {
    try {
        textfieldName.validate();
    } catch (InvalidInputExcpetion e) {
        // Error in the textfieldName
        // Eventually return if you need to validate only one field if an error is thrown
    }
    try {
        textfieldAge.validate();
    } catch (InvalidInputExcpetion e) {
        // Error in the textfieldAge
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent duplicating code, you can have validateInput take the text field as input, so it would validate one text field.  Then call it for each text field.

```
public void validateInput(TextField textField) {
    try {
        textField.validate();
    } catch (InvalidInputExcpetion e) {
        // Handle Error in the textField
    }
}
```

Then call it for each TextField:

```
validateInput(textfieldName);
validateInput(textfieldAge);
```